# How to use single CanDeactive Guard to protect different components, which contains method the guard needs

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using a CanDeactive guard to prevent leaving page with not saved changes. Each component has a checkChanged method:

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnChanges{
  checkChanged(){
    if(this.taskName==this.task.name
      ...){
      return false;
    }
    else{return true;}
  }
}
```

Deactive guard is like below:

```
export class ExampleDeactiveGuard implements CanDeactivate<ExampleComponent> {
  canDeactivate(
    component: ExampleComponent,
  ): Observable<boolean> | boolean |Promise<boolean> {
    return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
  }
}
```

And the guard is protecting the route:

```
{path:'ExampleComponent',component:ExampleComponent,canDeactivate:[ExampleDeactiveGuard]},
```

In this way it works, but if I have several components need to be protected, I need several guards respectively. Is there any way to use only one guard to protect all the components? Just like using the components as generic type.

Comment: Where are you using the "checkChanged" method?

Comment: It's super simple: `export class ExampleDeactiveGuard { canDeactivate(component: { canDeactivate?(): boolean; }) {
    return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate() : true;
  } }`